# como tomar foto con WebCam y almacenarla con laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

Estoy intentando tomar una foto y almacenarla con `laravel` en una carpeta de mi servidor pero no encuentro como implementarlo. intento usar **say cheese** pero no encuentro una librería para `laravel 5.5.` Alguien tiene alguna solución para este problema.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentarlo con este código en tu vista blade de Laravel:

```
<form method="POST" action="tu ruta para guardar la imagen" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div>
                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end" for="fotoid">Tomar una fotografía de usted</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="camera-container">
                        <div id="camera-wrapper">
                            <video id="camera-view" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></video>
                            <canvas id="canvas" style="display: none;"></canvas>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" id="tomar-foto">Tomar Fotografía</button>
                    </div>
                    <input accept="image/*" capture="camera" name="fotoid" id="fotoid" type="file" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
</form>

<style>
    .contenedor-formulario {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .camera-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    #camera-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const tomarFotoBtn = document.getElementById("tomar-foto");
        const imagenInput = document.getElementById("imagen");

        tomarFotoBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
            // Comprueba si el navegador es compatible con la API de getUserMedia
            if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                        video: true
                    })
                    .then(function(stream) {
                        // Crea un elemento de video para mostrar la vista previa de la cámara
                        const video = document.createElement("video");
                        video.setAttribute("autoplay", true);
                        video.srcObject = stream;

                        // Agrega el video al documento
                        document.body.appendChild(video);

                        // Escucha el evento click del botón para capturar la imagen
                        tomarFotoBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
                            const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                            const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

                            // Configura el canvas con el mismo tamaño que el video
                            canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
                            canvas.height = video.videoHeight;

                            // Captura la imagen del video y la dibuja en el canvas
                            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                            // Convierte el canvas a un archivo de imagen
                            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                                const imagenFile = new File([blob], "foto.png", {
                                    type: "image/png"
                                });
                                imagenInput.files = [imagenFile];

                                // Limpia el video y el canvas
                                stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
                                document.body.removeChild(video);
                                canvas.remove();
                            }, "image/png");
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.error("Error al acceder a la cámara:", error);
                    });
            } else {
                console.error("El navegador no es compatible con la captura de imágenes.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

En tu controlador puedes tomar los datos mediante la ruta de la siguiente manera:

```
public function handleForm(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('imagen')) {
        // Se cargó una imagen desde la galería
        $imagen = $request->file('imagen');
        // Procesar la imagen aquí
    } else {
        // No se cargó una imagen desde la galería, se capturó desde la cámara
        $imagen = $request->file('imagen');
        // Procesar la imagen aquí
    }

    // Resto del código del controlador
}
```